# Spring boot - setAttribute() method didn't take values from url into html file while it did into jsp one

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httpsession, setattribute

as what I mentioned on title, I step up into spring boot but when I come to content of HttpSession, I get a confuse here. I have a controller class as below:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(HttpServletRequest req) {
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    String product = req.getParameter("product");
    System.out.println("index page " + product);
    session.setAttribute("product", product);
    return "index";
}
}
```

and 1 file named index.html, 1 file named index.jsp respectively:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    HTML PAGE ${product}
</body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    JSP PAGE ${product}
</body>
</html>
```

and this is application.properties file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

index.html and index.jsp is in the same folder 'pages'. And I tried to replace value of suffix attribute in application.properties file into .jsp, then it works while it didn't when suffix value is .html.
This is result from .html and .jsp value:

[image]
[image]

Please help me, guys.

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK sorry but I couldn't get any idea from that page. I think it just mentioned about jsp page, not html.

Comment: Sorry but I think that wasn't what I mean. My jsp page is work correctly. My problem is in html page.
The parameter Volwagen didn't showed in html page.

Comment: My bad, don't worry.

Comment: Using straight Html is good when you have to use static content. If you want to stick to html and wan to move away from jsp, explore thymeleaf or freemarker. The whole idea is - you need to evaluate your expression at view level.

Comment: @AjayKumar ok thanks. I got it